# Contact us page receive information but not getting message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

See the contact us page here.

[image]

This is view file of contact page.

```
    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>Contact</h2>
      <h3><span>Contact Us</span></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">

        <div class="col-lg-9">
        <form action="{{route('contact.store')}}" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
            @csrf
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
              <div class="validate"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <div class="validate"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="loading">Loading</div>
            <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section><!-- End Contact Section -->
```

This is Controller code of contact us page.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    Contact::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'message' => $request->message,
    ]);
     \Session::flash('flash_message','successfully saved.');
     return redirect()->back();
}
```

Problem is i have a one page theme so i redirect same page after contact us details fill. But contact details here stay , not blank....what is it solution?

Answer (score 0):

don't use return back try by using return view

```
return view('viewName');
```

Comment: I did it, same problem, information store in database but not refresh page after submit button -@Monika

Comment: you can use someting like this "return redirect('home/dashboard');"

Comment: I did it actually but its not work.thats why i posted here? -@Monika

Answer (score 0):

Because your browser will do "back" when you use your code:

```
return redirect()->back();
```

Change to use this:

```
return redirect()->route('your_back_route_name');
```

I think that will work as reload page.

When it's not work, i think it is about your browser auto fill.
So, set you input value is empty when load.

```
<input value="" />
```

Comment: I try it, but didn't work. I think problem is another

Comment: I am sorry, can't help you more. Just wait another.

Comment: Can you come in my pc? you can check. -